# why colour not showing as argument in ggplot for R language

Tags: r

I was practicing course and stumbled upon argument "colour" in `aes` function so I assigned an object to differentiate data but R console is not showing colour as auto-suggestion argument.

Can you help me by explaining why?

** I am new to R**

Comment: Hi vishal! There could be multiple reasons (the object is a constant, you surrounded the object with quotes) but unless you show some of your data and your attempted code, it's almost impossible to know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that `colour`, `fill` and so forth does not show up as part of the `aes` arguments, is that `aes(...)` as a function does not necessarily take these arguments. The reaction of `aes(...)` depends on the specific `geom_[...]` (and `stat_[...]`), but most often contains at least `colour` and `color` and some `size` or `width` argument.

For specifics you should always check the documentation for the specific `geom_[...]` using for example `help(geom_point)` where the relevant aestethics are listed under `Aesthetics`. For the specific example we get:

> **Aesthetics**
>
> geom_point() understands the following aesthetics (required aesthetics are in bold):
>
> - **x**
> - **y**
> - alpha
> - colour
> - fill
> - group
> - shape
> - size
> - stroke
>
> Learn more about setting these aesthetics in vignette("ggplot2-specs").